# Apply Normal CDF to a spark dataframe column

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to create a new column in my Spark dataframe with PySpark calculated as the Normal CDF as shown in the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from scipy.stats import norm

mylist = [0.083, 0.219, 0.126]

df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, FloatType())
df.show()
df2 = df.withColumn("var2", norm.cdf(col("value")))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-70bb44c2d6d4> in <module>()
      6 df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, FloatType())
      7 df.show()
----> 8 df2 = df.withColumn("var2", norm.cdf(col("value")))

/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.pyc in cdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1726         args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
   1727         dtyp = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, np.float64], [])
-> 1728         x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
   1729         cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
   1730         cond1 = self._open_support_mask(x) & (scale > 0)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _(self, other)
    114     def _(self, other):
    115         jc = other._jc if isinstance(other, Column) else other
--> 116         njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc)
    117         return Column(njc)
    118     _.__doc__ = doc

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1246 
   1247     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1248         args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
   1249 
   1250         command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _build_args(self, *args)
   1210     def _build_args(self, *args):
   1211         if self.converters is not None and len(self.converters) > 0:
-> 1212             (new_args, temp_args) = self._get_args(args)
   1213         else:
   1214             new_args = args

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _get_args(self, args)
   1197                 for converter in self.gateway_client.converters:
   1198                     if converter.can_convert(arg):
-> 1199                         temp_arg = converter.convert(arg, self.gateway_client)
   1200                         temp_args.append(temp_arg)
   1201                         new_args.append(temp_arg)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py in convert(self, object, gateway_client)
    498         ArrayList = JavaClass("java.util.ArrayList", gateway_client)
    499         java_list = ArrayList()
--> 500         for element in object:
    501             java_list.add(element)
    502         return java_list

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

I have tried several alternatives like UDF and the like, but I have not got anything that works.
I get it with `toPandas()` but it causes the system to collapse when it comes to a very large table. Besides that then I have to take it back to Spark DataFrame.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using directly `norm.cdf` on `col("value")` will not work. `norm.cdf` expects a float, a you provide a column. To use this function, you need to use a `UDF` as you are suggesting it. Yet, there is a small trick.

This will throw an **ERROR** that's a bit hard to understand. This might be what you obtained when you tried it.

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> bad_norm_cdf = F.udf(lambda x: norm.cdf(x))
>>> df.withColumn("var2", bad_norm_cdf(df['value'])).show()
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
```

In fact, `norm.cdf` returns a `numpy.float64` which is not understood by spark. We can check it:

```py
>>> type(norm.cdf(.5))
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

So you simply need to cast this numpy float into a python float to make it work:

```py
>>> norm_cdf = F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.cdf(x)))
>>> df.withColumn("var2", norm_cdf(df['value'])).show()
+-----+------------------+
|value|              var2|
+-----+------------------+
|0.083|0.5330742289364767|
|0.219|0.5866749748631075|
|0.126|0.5501340385143536|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, more or less I understand the problem I have.
Perhaps the example I gave is not the most appropriate, since my real dataset is of the Decimal type (18.3) and it seems that it does not work.
The error I think is also related to the types:
``` File "/opt/.......cture.py", line 1734, in cdf
    place(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''```

Comment: Ok, i have it, just move the `float` inside the cdf and work it.